# GridViewDataColumn SourceUpdated on child property

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, telerik, radgridview

I'm using caliburn micro and Telerik controls for an application.

I have a RadGrivView binded to a collection of PurchaseDetails with an editable column for the Purchase Price of the row. Binding is working correctly at updating the PurchasePrice value on the PurchaseDetails object, but I need to update other values on the View which are binded to other objects.

I would like to raise an event on the Model whenever the PurchasePrice is updated.
I've tried NotifyOnSourceUpdated, at column and grid level with no luck.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ShowGroupPanel="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding PurchaseDetails}">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataFormatString="N2" 
                                             SourceUpdated="FrameworkContentElement_OnSourceUpdated"
                                            TargetUpdated="FrameworkContentElement_OnTargetUpdated"
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding .PurchasePrice, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataFormatString="N2" 
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding .Amount.Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is (partly) designed for this purpose. If you correctly implement it in your `PurchaseDetails` class, then you'll be able to handle the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event on that object:

```
SelectedPurchaseDetail.PropertyChanged += Detail_PropertyChanged;

...

private void Detail_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "PurchasePrice")
    {
        // PurchasePrice was changed... update other view model properties here
    }
}
```